# Visual Studio 2015 Excluded from Build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

When I'm working with a VS project, when I want to build some files but not the others, I would go to Solution Explorer, right click on the files I don't want to build, Properties, and set Excluded from Build to "Yes". I find it cumbersome to do this for a dozen files. Is there a shortcut or a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: File not including in project?

Comment: Build > Configuration Manager > untick the "Build" checkbox.